# Reading in pound sign and speech marks

Tags: java, android, string, char

I am currently reading in a file into java where the file contains list of ("char symbol" "tab" "6 comma seperated booleans" "new line")

I am reading it in fine and splitting it up ok - however i have a problem whereby the pound sign and speech marks are being read in as a black diamond with a question mark in it. This is screwing everything up as i need to be able to identify which codes go with which char symbol.

I am reading in using:

```
public void read()
 {

  int i = 0;
  try{
    // Open the file
    InputStream is = am.open("combinations.txt");
    // Get the object of DataInputStream
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String strLine;
    //Read File Line By Line
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null && i < 53)   {
     String[] sep1 = strLine.split("\t");
     String[] sep2 = sep1[1].split(",");
     entries[i] = new Entry(sep1[0].charAt(0), new CellPattern(Boolean.valueOf(sep2[0]),
       Boolean.valueOf(sep2[1]),Boolean.valueOf(sep2[2]),Boolean.valueOf(sep2[3]),
       Boolean.valueOf(sep2[4]),Boolean.valueOf(sep2[5])));
     i++;
    }
    //Close the input stream
    in.close();
    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample line from the file you are reading in that has problems? How are you displaying the characters? charAt(0) should return a # sign just fine...

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read a text file. You don't need it so please remove it as people might copy this code.

Answer (score 2):

It is an encoding problem, try changing your BufferedReader line to:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
```

I'm not sure which encoding you'll need, so you may want to try a few different ones.

Edit: 
Try "ISO-8859-1"